# Handling Ajax auto redirect

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, heroku

I am struggling from 2 days to solve the issue with my Laravel app which I have uploaded on Heroku server. This application is uploading a file through ajax request showing upload progress also on the page and it returns json response.

I have set the `Content-Type: application/json` and `X-CSRF-TOKEN` is also valid in the header but still after completing the upload instead of returning valid json response, it setting status to 301 and 302 and move to home page.

I have tested this Laravel app on my local server and its very stable there. I am thinking if there is any way to pause chrome before loading the redirection page by hitting a breakpoint, so I could know whats happening before the redirection. I have already tried this in console:

`window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() { debugger; }, false)`

but it never trigger a breakpoint. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your header `contentType` or `Content-Type`?

Comment: @Quezler typo mistake, I have confirmed it to be `Content-Type`

Comment: Any more context about the application that might help us understand?

Comment: Not sure what more information should be shared as Heroku is acting really odd. I have also checked the `upload_max_filesize` but that is also correct.

Comment: This is only happening in ajax and on regular form submission it uploading files well.

Comment: Would it be possible to have a link to the application so we can experience it ourself? if this includes usernames and passwords you should not share it on this site though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170301/discussion-between-codelearner-and-quezler).

Answer (score 0):

Finally after 2 hectic days in scrubbing my head with Heroku server, I figured out that Heroku Apache server requires that Laravel route should be set to handle both `POST` and `GET` method. In my case I have to use this:

`Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/xls2db', 'HomeController@xls2db')->name('xls2db');`

This does makes sense because after Ajax POST method it returns `json` response which will only be handled if the route accepts GET method also.

On my local server I was testing my app with `php artisan serve` which can GET json response with only POST route.